# jquery keep/retain selected option of first select box when i ad to it next select box

Tags: jquery

Have default select box (first select box)

Select some option

With $.post send to external php and based on selected option (value), from mysql get next select box

Ad the next select box to the first select box

Problem is that for the first select box do not keep/retain selected option

Here is the code (instead of $.post and external php i just define jquery variable that includes the next select box)

Html

```
<span id="span_topics">

<select class="topics" id="0" style="width:135px;">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1">0_One</option>
<option value="2">0_Two</option>
</select>    

</span>
```

And jquery

```
$(document).on('change', '.topics', function(){

id_of_selected_class = this.id;
closest_upper_level_id = $(this).val();

alert('here can see selected option');    
var selected_option = $('#' + id_of_selected_class).find(":selected").val();
$('#' + id_of_selected_class + ' option').prop('selected', false) .filter('[value="' + selected_option + '"]') .prop('selected', true);
alert('here can see selected option');

var topic_names = '<select class="topics" id="1" style="width:135px;"><option value="">Select</option><option value="1">1_One</option><option value="2">1_Two</option></select>';

alert( $("#span_topics").html() );
//In alert i can not see selected option; How to get to see?    
$("#span_topics").html( $("#span_topics").html() + topic_names );    
alert('but here can NOT see selected option');    

});
```

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/dr66bmcm/7/

If for example from `id="0"` i select `<option value="1">0_One</option>`, then after executing jquery for `id="0"` i see `<option value="">Select</option>`. How to keep/retain to see `<option value="1">0_One</option>`?

Comment: I am confused! **id_of_selected_class** is id of span not "select"?!

Comment: @AliSheikhpour it is `id` of select (`id` for selected class `.topics`). I will chang span id name. Seems i have made a mess because these `topics`

Comment: There is a problem in your fiddle, it shows **only one time** entire of select with no selected item. Did you want to display it two times?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with one time. I select some option want to see the select box with selected option. And to the select box will ad next select box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of changing whole html:

```
$("#span_topics").html( $("#span_topics").html() + topic_names );
```

append new data to existing html:

```
$("#span_topics").append(topic_names);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dr66bmcm/9/)

```
   $('#' + id_of_selected_class + ' option').prop('selected', false) .filter('[value="' + selected_option + '"]').attr("selected","selected");;
    alert('here can see selected option');
```

Comment: .attr("selected","selected") will result to <option selected="selected"> which is not proper way to set option as selected. However you are true that he has not set the **selected** in correct way.